# UDP Datagrams in gaming, what happens when they get lost?

Tags: java, udp, datagram, game-development

Let's say you want to make a real-time game, perhaps a 2D topdown game.
Things you would do in the game to keep it simple are:

- Connect to the server
- Move the player with the keys
- Possibly press space bar to attack
- Send a chat message

But what would happen if a datagram from any of these situations get lost?
What would you do?

1) **Connecting to the server**

If you send a UDP datagram to the server, the server would take your IP and port and then create a player
based on an ID it gives you, this it how it identifies you every time it receives a datagram from you.

But what if upon "connection" (not actually a connection, just a udp datagram that says 'make me a part of your server'), this initial datagram gets lost. Is it right to say that you would just resend it if after a certain period of time you did not receive a reply back from the server?

2) **Moving the player/attacking**

If at any time we move the player/press a movement key/attack key, we would send a keystroke
to the server telling it what key we pressed/released.
The server would then relay this to all the other clients.

But what if this keystroke datagram gets lost? Either upon client->server or server->clients.
Because keystrokes are happening all the time, is it efficient to just resend it all the time?
Or would we just ignore the fact that it got lost along the way because there's a chance that if you press a key again it will most likely make it the next time?

3) **Sending a chat message**

This would be something that MUST reach the server.
If it got lost along the way, after a certain period of time if we did not receive a reply from the other side/receiving end, do we re-send it?

### ***TL;DR***

Is it okay to just keep resending datagrams if we know after a certain period of time it did not reach?
And also, what about confirming if a datagram got successfully sent?

If client sends a chat message to the server, and the server receives it, should the server send a reply back to the client to confirm that it received it? What would happen if that reply got lost, what then?

Answer (score 1):

Typically games using UDP have an application level protocol on-top so they can send some messages reliably and others not. If they wanted to send everything reliably they would be better off using TCP. However fast-paced games can not afford the delay TCP introduces and if the packet does get lost it's often too late to re-send it!

One way to implement reliable messages is, like you suppose, to send an ACKnowledgment reply that this particular packet was received - but what if that gets dropped you ask? The sender of the reliable packet typically re-sends a certain number of times (e.g. 3 times) and if no ACK is still received the sender then assumes the peer has dropped.

An excellent place for articles and game networking including how to minimise data sent is [Shawn Hargreaves blog](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html#networking). (This is focused at C# XNA but the same logic applies irrespective of language/framework/platform).

Lastly:

- Game network programming for fast paces games is hard. If your game is slow and/or turn based consider TCP and a lock-step approach which makes things considerably easier.
- Don't re-invent the wheel, there are libraries that do things such as implementing reliability on top of UDP for when you need it, e.g. [FalconUDP](http://falconudp.codeplex.com). Though this is a .NET one - I would like to see a Java port :)

Answer (score 0):

If a datagram gets lost there is nothing the receiver can do, because he doesn't know about it. It's up to the sender to re-send, and it's up to you to design an ACK-based or NACK-based protocol so that the receiver knows when to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is okay to just keep resending UDP datagrams depends on how the server treats the data in the datagrams.  For example, if you resend a chat message, and the server receives both the original message and the resent message, does the server display the message twice?  Note that you might end up resending even if the original message was received, because the reply to the original message might have gotten lost or delayed.

The best bet is to use TCP instead of UDP, since TCP has already solved all these problems for you.  World of Warcraft, for example, started with TCP for chat and UDP for gameplay, and eventually converted to TCP for everything.